# Consider the points $P(0, -2, 0), Q(6, 1,-2), R(2, 4, 1)$, Find the area of the triangle PQR.

Tags: triangles

Consider the points below.
$$P(0, -2, 0), Q(6, 1,-2), R(2, 4, 1)$$
Find the area of the triangle PQR.

Comment: Done! What else do you want me to do?

Comment: You do have in particular $$A=\frac12\det\begin{vmatrix}a_1&a_2&1\\b_1&b_2&1\\c_1&c_2&1\end{vmatrix}$$

Comment: you can use cross product and divide by 2 the area